# Lenovo core i3 20236, is not detecting bootable usb for windows 7

Tags: windows, usb, bootable-media

I am trying to install windows 7 through bootable usb, but my Lenovo laptop core I3 20236 is not detecting USB in start. Currently windows 8 is installed in this laptop. I am not able to find boot manager in this laptop.

Comment: What is the default boot order? It is a setting in BIOS.
Have you tried pressing F12 to open the boot menu?

Comment: I am not able to find boot manager in this laptop. I have tried by pressing F12, but it just enhances brightness

Comment: Have you tried pressing F12 when you see the Lenovo logo at start up?

Comment: yes, it only increases brightness,

Comment: Somewhere on your keyboard, usually in the lower left corner of the keyboard you have a key that says "Fn". Hold that key and press F12 at start up and see what happens?

Comment: I have pressed F12 with Fn key. Now it shows 3 options. 1. Window Boot Manager () 2. EF I Network for IPV 4 3. EF I Network for IPV 6. Here only first option works while others two didn't. when I hit enter key with first option it started window 8

Comment: Did you try these steps?: 
1. Open the Charm Bar by pressing Windows Key-C   
2. Click on Settings   
3. Click on Change PC Settings   
4. Click on General   
5. Scroll to the bottom and click on Advanced Startup -> Restart Now    
6. Click on Use A Device   
7. Click on Boot Menu.   

From: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht076906

Comment: i have tried this it showed a msg, "System does not have any USB Boot option, please select other boot options in Boot Manager Manu" when I click on OK, it brings 3 options. 1. Window Boot Manager () 2. EF I Network for IPV 4 3. EF I Network for IPV 6.

Comment: And the option "Windows Boot Manager" only boots Windows? If it does, try with pressing "F1" or "Fn" + "F1" during start up (when you see the Lenovo logo) and see if you are able to enter the BIOS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 uses a hybrid shutdown that bypasses the BIOS (UEFI) startup mechanism. First you must shut down completely e.g. open a CMD prompt and type

shutdown /f /s /t 0

Then, **before** restarting the computer, **hold down** the key used to go to BIOS: see the [G500 manual](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/g410_g510_ug_en.pdf) and this [Lenovo tech note](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht076906).

Comment: I have pressed F12 with Fn key. Now it shows 3 options. 1. Window Boot Manager () 2. EF I Network  for IPV 4 3. EF I Network  for IPV 6. Here only first option works while others two didn't. when I hit enter key with first option it started window 8.